# d3.transition().attr('x', y) does not work when d3.attr('x', y) does

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following works (the circle will move to the new location at the point(s) provided)

```
d3target
  .attr('cx', newCX )
  .attr('cy', newCY )
```

but these do not:

```
d3target
  .transition()
  .attr('cx', newCX )
  .attr('cy', newCY )
   // .duration(1000) // Still doesn't work with or without the duration
```

and nor does this: (by providing a starting value [as suggested by API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#content))

```
d3target
  .attr('cx', originalCX )
  .attr('cy', originalCY )
  .transition()
  .attr('cx', newCX )
  .attr('cy', newCY )
   // .duration(1000) // Still doesn't work with or without the duration
```

The circles do not animate, nor move at all. We tried manually setting the `dur` to 1 second to ensure that the animation wasn't finishing or skipping because it was too small for it to be noticed or skipped or the like.

We have tried and looked at lots of possibilities as to why, so any thoughts as to why or what else to try is greatly appreciated.

Basic info for reference:
The d3Target looks as follows, and to what we know is correct, given that the first code block works by just adjusting the `attr`s directly without a `transition()` call.

[image: d3Target description]

Comment: Can you post a working snippet? That should work so the problem will be elsewhere.

Comment: can you tell if you are using this code on server side or client side? transition does not work on server side code(eg:nodejs)

Comment: @Raj  The code is being served to the client.   The code runs client side.  We have confirmed that the d3.select/d3.selectAll works and returns a proper d3 object, hence the first code block working.   Any other thoughts?

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Apparently you can't edit bounty messages.   The codebase is at https://github.com/VT-CHCI/SoundOfFractions/blob/master/app/javascripts/backbone/views/measure/measureRepView.js

Comment: Are you sure d3 knows how to interpolate values provided in `…CX` and `…CY`?

Comment: @chrisFrisina When you say that it "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error message? Does it not interpolate, but "jump" to the new value? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Yes.   The code has been working for several years.  Please also take a look at the 'three little circles' example here : http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff updated to clarify.  They don't move at all.

Comment: @chrisFrisina My best guess is that another transition is interrupting it. Remember that as soon as you call `.transition()` on a selection, all existing transitions are cancelled -- I think this is what's happening here. You have lots of other transitions going on in the code and it's not obvious to me how they relate.

Comment: I actually saw something similar to this in my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33455980/16363).  Have you tried using `attrTween` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p4148ppu/1/)?

Answer (score 2):

First assign you transiton ( return of the transition method ) to a variable, then try `console.log(transition_selection.empty())`. If it's false then you know that you have something to transition.

Second try: `transition_selection.each('start', function(){ console.log('started'); }).each('interrupt', function() {console.log('interrupted');}).each('end', function(){ console.log('ended'); });`

This way you'll be able to see if transition was started and was interrupted.

Third try:  `transition.attr('cx', function (d) { console.log( 'attr got assigned'); ) });`

This way you will know if the value you provided for 'cx' was read.

Actually try all of the above in the same run. So that you can see what happens in what order.

Always try naming you transitions. `d3traget.transition('somename')`

This way you can run many transitions on the same selection in parallel. If you run more than one "unnamed" transitions on the same selection, the second transition will stop the first one.

Hope any of what I've given to you will help you resolve your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The transition works using the following simplified code:

html:

```
  <svg height='500' width='500'>
        <circle id='circ' cx='50' cy='50' r='10'></circle>   
    </svg>
```

js:

```
var d3target = d3.select('#circ');

d3target
  .transition()
  .attr('cx', 100 )
  .attr('cy', 100 )
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4148ppu/)

This means there is something else in the code that is stopping your transition from working. 
Following the link to your code, as far as I can see this is where you have the transition going on:

```
 if(this.parentMeasureModel.get('timesRecorded') !== 0) {
    d3target
      .attr('cx', newCX )
      .attr('cy', newCY )

    setTimeout(function(){
      d3target
        .attr('cx', originalCX )
        .attr('cy', originalCY )
    }, dur);
  // Otherwise we use the standard method
  } else {      
    d3target.transition()
      .attr('cx', newCX )
      .attr('cy', newCY )
      .duration(dur)
      .each('end',function() {                   // as seen above
        d3.select(this).                         // this is the object 
          transition()                           // a new transition!
            .attr('cx', originalCX )    // we could have had another
            .attr('cy', originalCY )    // we could have had another
            .duration(dur);                  // .each("end" construct here.
       });
  }
}
```

The difference between the two is the `dur` variable and the each method. Try using an actual value for the `dur` variable and removing the each method. If it works then your issue lies there.

Comment: Unfortunately this JS does not work.   A problem is that we are change which beats are being presented.   Then we animate the beats using the same function.   The `target` and `dur` coming in are correct, and can be validated by placing a `debugger` statement.   Your assessment that there must be something else is likely.   But what?  As far we have diagnosed, D3 is the concern.   This may be an assumption, but it is based on years of D3 experience and verifying each code block works or doesn't.   I am still working on a Plnkr, and almost there.

Comment: As your code points out, we are checking whether or not it has been replaced, so we can use the normal `transition()` when it is normal, and we can use the `setTimeout()` (our current duct tape patch) to animate until we can figure out the cause for the discrepancy.   You can see within this function that the `d3target` remains the SAME, as does the `dur`, yet the implementation of the animation has to change because it is failing in the "recorded" case.   Just to confirm, the d3target is "correct" as far as we know and according to viewing it in the terminal for its structure.

Comment: I did have a look but it's difficult to see where else it could be going wrong without seeing how it is called. Would love to help you out, it's an interesting issue. Will wait for your plunkr to get a better idea.